# Incrementing FK value instead of using selected FK value

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I built a PHP web app with the Yii framework, using a postgresql db.

Here are my tables `apresentante`, `veiculo`, `ferro` and `lavagem`:

```
CREATE TABLE apresentante
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  morada character varying(50),
  cp character varying(15),
  nif integer NOT NULL,
  telefone integer,
  telemovel integer,
  codigo integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT apresentante_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE veiculo
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  matricula character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  classe character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_veiculo PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE lavagem
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  veiculo_id serial NOT NULL,
  data date NOT NULL,
  apresentante_id smallint NOT NULL,
  ferro_id serial NOT NULL,
  apresentante_paga boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_lavagem_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT id_apresentante_fk FOREIGN KEY (apresentante_id)
      REFERENCES apresentante (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT id_ferro_fk FOREIGN KEY (ferro_id)
      REFERENCES ferro (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT id_veiculo_fk FOREIGN KEY (veiculo_id)
      REFERENCES veiculo (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE ferro
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  ferro integer NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_ferro PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITHOUT OIDS;
```

I created the models and forms with Gii.
The problem is that when I try to insert a row into table `lavagem` it doesn't get the selected FK value, instead it increments the FK values to values that doesn't exist in the FK table.

The exception error:

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: insert or update on table "lavagem" violates foreign key constraint "id_ferro_fk"
DETAIL: Key (ferro_id)=(4) is not present in table "ferro".. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO "lavagem" ("data", "apresentante_id", "apresentante_paga") VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've an error in your schema. Foreign keys like:

```
veiculo_id serial NOT NULL,
```

Should actually look more like:

```
veiculo_id int NOT NULL,
```

It's the id field in the original table that needs to be an auto-incrementing integer; rather than the field that is referencing it.

Comment: My FK was auto-incrementing.